# Why Joomla shows contents with any URL?

Tags: joomla, routes, joomla3.0

I found a bug in my Joomla 3.6.4 site when I searched in google for test purpose.
For example I have a content with ID `34` and alias `myalias`
Now Unexpectedly all of below URLs load my content:

```
http://example.com/test-test-test/34-myalias
http://example.com/mytest/34-myalias
http://example.com/hellowwwwwwwwwwwww/34-myalias
http://example.com/aything/34-myalias
```

and so on.
This is not TRUE at all!! The content must be loaded just in my predefined menu item. For example I assign a new Menu Item in Menu Manager like `definedmenu` witch shows content `34`. So below URL should works only:

```
http://example.com/definedmenu/34-myalias
```

What is the problem. It's bad for my website SEO...
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://example.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=34&name=ram&age=30
here

```
http://example.com/index.php is a base url
```

and

```
option=com_content&view=article&id=34&name=ram&age=30
```

these are input variables

when we change url to SEO url

```
http://example.com/index.php/content/article/34/ram/30
```

so

```
http://example.com/test-test-test/34-myalias
http://example.com/mytest/34-myalias
http://example.com/hellowwwwwwwwwwwww/34-myalias
http://example.com/aything/34-myalias
```

"test-test-test" treat as input variable
"mytest" treat as input variable

but each component have some restriction in component route, in content "id-alias" format so "34-myalias" but here id is important

```
http://example.com/test-test-test/34-myaliasdfdfdfd it will work

http://example.com/test-test-test/34-sdsdsdmyalias it will work
```

but

```
http://example.com/test-test-test/sdsd34-myalias it will not work
```

Comment: I know this. But what is the solution?!

Answer (score 0):

This is why many people turn to SEO components like

RSSEO! https://www.rsjoomla.com/joomla-extensions/joomla-seo.html

or

sh404SEF https://weeblr.com/joomla-seo-analytics-security/sh404sef